# Redirect form after button click depending on dropdown box selection

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am writing a form in which I want the user to be able to redirect to one of four individual pages based on a selection. To do this I have implemented a dropdown select box with all of my options. What I want is the selection made in this box to change the form redirect url when the button is hit to submit. I have seen a few other examples of this problem but have encountered some errors with them. For example I attempted a jQuery fix that I saw but it redirected the user to a new page as soon as the dropdown option was selected.

Here is my form code

```
<form action="" id="search-form" method="post" onChange="">
    <input name="retURL" value="thankyou.html" type="hidden">
        <label for="firstname" class="half first-half">
      <input type="text" name="First Name" id="firstname" placeholder="FIRST NAME*" autofocus required>
    </label>
    <label for="lastname" class="half second-half">
      <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="lastname" placeholder="LAST NAME*" required>
    </label>
     <label for="email" >
      <input type="email" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL*" required>
    </label>
    <label for="phone" >
      <input type="tel" name="Phone" id="phone" placeholder="PHONE*" required >
    </label>
    <label>
    <select id="selectbox" name="">
        <option value="0" selected>PROPERTY OF INTEREST*</option>
        <option value="thankyou1.html">Adako Crossing</option>
        <option value="thankyou2.html">Hayes Haven</option>
        <option value="thankyou3.html">Pinion</option>
        <option value="thankyouall.html">All Properties</option>
    </select>
    </label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="COMMENTS"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" id="get_info" name="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show us your jquery?

Comment: Try tying your redirect to the submit event on the form instead of the change on the selectbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hidden `<input>` field, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField">
```

and upon user selecting an option, save the URL into the hidden input field:

```
$("#selectbox").on("change", function(){
    $('#myHiddenField').val(this.value);
});
```

Then, your javascript can look *something like* this (untested):

```
$('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
    var url = $('#myHiddenField').val();
    alert(url);
    window.location.replace(url);
    //e.preventDefault(); //<== prevent form submission, IF DESIRED
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLrZq/1/)**

---

personally, I prefer to use a submit button that is `type="button"` (instead of type=submit) and then use jQuery to submit the form when I am ready. That gets around all the issues of using `preventDefault()`, etc.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit It" id="get_info">
```

and then the jQuery:

```
$('#get_info').click(function() {
    var url = $('#myHiddenField').val();
    alert(url);
    window.location.replace(url);
    $('#search-form').submit();
});
```

**Then again, I'm not sure if you can combine the `submit()` and `window.location.replace()` methods...***

Comment: This works in the fiddle but not on my site, I'm confused.

I uploaded the site [here](http://www.cs.unca.edu/~ruggiejl/Element360/LandManagementSqueeze/index.html) to try and figure it out.

Comment: (1) Did you add the hidden `<input>` element? (2) Have you correctly matched that element's ID with your jQuery code to store the URL data in that element? (3) Using Google Chrome -- After changing the select option, right-click where you expect to find the hidden input element and choose `Inspect Element` from the popup -- see if the correct URL has been stored.

Comment: I have another idea for you, btw. Instead of using `window.location.replace(url)` on the client side, you can add that url into a hidden element in the form (perhaps just move `#myHiddenField` between the form codes, and add the `name="myHiddenField"` attribute to the control so it gets sent with form). Then, on the PHP side, get that value into a variable: `$newLoc = $_POST['myHiddenField'];` and use PHP to redirect the user to that new location (after processing the form data): `echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url="' .$newloc. '">';`

Comment: I have fixed it so the correct url is stored. How do I change it so the from redirects to that value now? As in, how do i set the URL to the form action so that when it submits it redirects.

Comment: That is really a new question. Please close this question (by selecting a correct answer) and post a new question and I (among many others, I am sure, because a new question will appear at top of list) will be happy to help. Please also remember to upvote any answers that have been helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of the code, I can suggest something like this:

```
$("#selectbox").on("change", function(){   
    window.location.replace(this.value); 
});
```

If you are using php, change value of options to "?goto=0..1,2,3" etc and redirect them in php(which is better option, I think)

**EDIT**

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wS6EZ/3/

here's another solution:

in **html**, add hidden field inside your submit form. I've added type=text in fiddle for example sake.

```
<input type="hidden" id="redirect" value="NULL"/>
```

in **jquery**

```
$("#selectbox").on("change", function(){
    $("#redirect").val(this.value);
});
```

in **php**, add this, which pretty much mean: when form is submitted redirect to hidden field value (which we change with jquery)

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
     header("Location: {$_POST["redirect"]}"); 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Indeed this works but it changes the page as soon as the dropdown option is selected, I want it to change the redirect url for when the submit button is pressed.

Comment: are you using php or asp?